# Result of an SQL query in a conditional branch

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I'm trying to learn how to use the graphic modeler; it's not an easy task.

In this case, I want to check in a PostgreSQL database that a table is not empty. For this I perform a "PostgreSQL execute and load SQL" algorithm to retrieve the result in a table (`SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM schema.table`).

Then I try to use a conditional branch to check the value of **total** but I can't get that value back, I don't know how to target it. I did check the dependencies between the pgSQL query and the conditional branch, and tested various calls such as "`attributes()['total'] > 0`", "`@total > 0`" or "`parameter('total')`".

Do you have an idea?

EDIT : it looks like I need to use @Request_table_OUTPUT, but I can't seem to specifically target the **total** result...